# Does Kafka scale well for big number of clients?

Tags: apache-kafka, scalability

I know Kafka can handle tons of traffic. However, how well does it scale for big number of concurrent clients?

Each client would have their own unique `group_id` (and as consequence Kafka would be keeping track of each one's offsets).

Would that be an issue for Kafka 0.9+ with offsets stored internally?

Would that be an issue for Kafka 0.8 with offsets stored in Zookeeper?

Comment: What do you consider to be a "big number of concurrent clients"?  `10`, `1,000`, `1,000,000`, `1,000,000,000`, ...?

Comment: Well, initially limited to few dozens, but depending on the answer I'm wondering if it's viable to open it up to 100,000+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Kafka users such as LinkedIn have reported in the past that a single Kafka broker can support ~10K client connections.  This number may vary depending on hardware, configuration, etc.

As long as the request rate is not too high, the limiting factor is probably just the [open-file-descriptors](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) limit as configured in the operating system, see e.g. http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html#file-descriptors-and-mmap for more information.

Comment: [i]"LinkedIn have reported in the past that a single Kafka broker can support ~10K client connections"[/i] I've been trawling through LinkedIn Engineering posts about Kafka, but I can't quite find it. Could you add a link?

Comment: That info might have been shared at a conference or through personal discussions we had with their team -- unfortunately I can't remember.  Jun Rao (co-creator of Kafka and my voice-of-truth for such questions) confirmed that info to me, in case that helps.